# Custom objects for model in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC. In [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model), entity framework is used form the 'model' part. I am used to OOP in programming. So, i would like to use custom objects instead of entity framework. Is it possible at all?

Sorry if this a foolish question.

Comment: Main question: Is it possible at all? Answer: Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an mvc action injects what it wants in a view.

```
return View("test");
```

A razor view can display whatever was injected in it.

```
<body>@Model</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible at all?

Of course, MVC is in no way bound to Entity Framework. It's even advisable to create your own ViewModels, instead of using entity classes for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom object as model but you need also a layer to access real data.

EF allows you to create model and provides a framework to access/modify data.